# Embarcadero FireMonkey 3D camera rotation and zoom

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I search a example for camera rotation and zooming in FireMonkey 3D. Like use left mouse button to rotate the camera around the scene and use the mouse wheel to zoom in and out.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: One gotcha to watch for is you may need to disable hit testing on background objects for the viewport to receive the mouse events.

Answer (score 1):

The following form shows a simple demo of this, just save the .fmx and .pas files and add the form to an FMX application. The key parts are having the Camera & nested light object on a separate X & Y axis to the DummyObject which is the camera target. Having the X & Y as separate dummy objects make the rotation vertical and horizontal which is desirable in some situation. You can also merge the DummyX & DummyY objects into a single DummyXY object which will give a more real world rotation style, but will depend on your needs as to which is preferable.

MainForm.pas:

```
unit MainForm;

interface

uses
  FMX.Forms, FMX.Materials, System.Math.Vectors, FMX.Types3D, FMX.Objects3D, FMX.Controls3D, FMX.Viewport3D,
  System.Classes, FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Layouts, FMX.MaterialSources, System.Types, System.UITypes;

type

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Viewport3D: TViewport3D;
    DummyX: TDummy;
    DummyObject: TDummy;
    CameraZ: TCamera;
    Light1: TLight;
    LayoutMain: TLayout;
    DummyY: TDummy;
    Cone1: TCone;
    LightMaterialSource1: TLightMaterialSource;
    procedure Viewport3DMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
    procedure Viewport3DMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
    procedure Viewport3DMouseWheel(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; WheelDelta: Integer; var Handled: Boolean);
  private
    FDown: TPointF;
    procedure DoZoom(aIn: Boolean);
  public
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

const
  CAMERA_MAX_Z = -2;
  CAMERA_MIN_Z = -200;
  ZOOM_STEP = 2;

procedure TForm1.DoZoom(aIn: Boolean);
var
  newZ: Single;
begin
  if aIn then
    newZ := CameraZ.Position.Z + ZOOM_STEP
  else
    newZ := CameraZ.Position.Z - ZOOM_STEP;

  if (newZ < CAMERA_MAX_Z) and (newZ > CAMERA_MIN_Z) then
    CameraZ.Position.Z := newZ;
end;

procedure TForm1.Viewport3DMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
begin
  FDown := PointF(X, Y);
end;

procedure TForm1.Viewport3DMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
begin
  if (ssLeft in Shift) then
  begin
    DummyX.RotationAngle.X := DummyX.RotationAngle.X - ((Y - FDown.Y) * 0.3);
    DummyY.RotationAngle.Y := DummyY.RotationAngle.Y + ((X - FDown.X) * 0.3);
    FDown := PointF(X, Y);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Viewport3DMouseWheel(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; WheelDelta: Integer; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  DoZoom(WheelDelta > 0);
end;

end.
```

MainForm.fmx:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 592
  ClientWidth = 713
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object LayoutMain: TLayout
    Align = Client
    Size.Width = 713.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 592.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabOrder = 2
    object Viewport3D: TViewport3D
      Align = Client
      Camera = CameraZ
      Size.Width = 713.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 592.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      UsingDesignCamera = False
      OnMouseDown = Viewport3DMouseDown
      OnMouseMove = Viewport3DMouseMove
      OnMouseWheel = Viewport3DMouseWheel
      object DummyX: TDummy
        Width = 1.000000000000000000
        Height = 1.000000000000000000
        Depth = 1.000000000000000000
        object DummyY: TDummy
          Width = 1.000000000000000000
          Height = 1.000000000000000000
          Depth = 1.000000000000000000
          object CameraZ: TCamera
            AngleOfView = 45.000000000000000000
            Target = DummyObject
            Position.Z = -20.000000000000000000
            Width = 1.000000000000000000
            Height = 1.000000000000000000
            Depth = 1.000000000000000000
            object Light1: TLight
              Color = claWhite
              LightType = Directional
              SpotCutOff = 180.000000000000000000
              Width = 1.000000000000000000
              Height = 1.000000000000000000
              Depth = 1.000000000000000000
            end
          end
        end
      end
      object DummyObject: TDummy
        Width = 1.000000000000000000
        Height = 1.000000000000000000
        Depth = 1.000000000000000000
        object Cone1: TCone
          Width = 1.000000000000000000
          Height = 1.000000000000000000
          Depth = 1.000000000000000000
          SubdivisionsCap = 3
          MaterialSource = LightMaterialSource1
        end
      end
    end
  end
  object LightMaterialSource1: TLightMaterialSource
    Diffuse = claWhite
    Ambient = xFF202020
    Emissive = claNull
    Specular = xFF606060
    Shininess = 30
    Left = 436
    Top = 56
  end
end
```

I pulled this from a demo somewhere, but works great for my needs. Should work for Delphi XE5 and up.

Answer (score -2):

You can rotate the camera with dragging and zoom with wheel. The important thing is that rotating on different axis should all be handled on different nested objects so that the rotation calculation should effect each other as we expect in real world.

Comment: @GlenMorse here's the link originally posted: http://delphiscience.wordpress.com/2012/11/14/making-a-pipe-with-bend-feature-using-delphi-firemonkey/

Comment: Wow, an answer that totally doesn't help. How about some code? Every idiot knows that it should be dragging and mousewheel events.